# React.StrictMode is always enabled

Tags: reactjs, react-18

I am updating some apps to react 18. However I do not want to use strict mode on development. While searching how to disable "React strict mode" online I can see that all I need to do is not wrap my app in `<React.StrictMode>`. However I am not wrapping my application in `<React.StrictMode>` and useEffect still mounts twice (before it wasn't obviously). These applications were not created using `create-react-app`.

react version `18.2.0` (also tried version `18.0.0` and the result is the same)

Comment: please help to add your code.

Comment: Also, how did you created your app (using NextJs or manually setting everything up)?

Comment: @AndriusOlišauskas Manually setting up my own webpack config file.